# How many combinatioons are possible?

Tags: math

I have 4 numbers 0, 1, 2, 3 How many combinations of 3 digits can I make? Numbers can be repeated.

example
000
001
011
111
324
123 etc etc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical computer programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 to the third power

```
4^3 = 64 combinations
```

to get all combinations run something like

```
digits = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for i in digits:
  for j in digits:
    for k in digits:
      print("{} {} {}".format(i, j, k))
```